# How to implement my own CMS hosted on a remote domain in all my projects?

Tags: php, cms, apache, content-management

So, I'm developing my own CMS which dynamically adjusts to the settings I have set on a specific domain.

I just developed this whole CMS on my local machine and now facing the problem that I have multiple projects, each on a different domain (same host provider though, don't know if that's relevant?). On my localhost it's no problem because I just point to the specific CMS folder.

__

Example: My CMS Files are in a subdirectory of **www.mycms.com** like `www.mycms.com/cms/` and my project ist hosted on **www.project-a.com**.

Now I assumed I just need to include my multiple CMS files like `www.mycms.com/cms/classes/user.php`, etc.

Since this gives me a `permission denied` error and everyone on the web seems to be against `allow_url_fopen` because of security risks, I need to know if I have other possibilities to make this work without putting all the files of `/cms/` into each domain each time. Because that would force me to upload all CMS files all the time to each domain seperately, even if I just change minor things.

I don't know if this is compareable to an API like the Google Maps API or something where you also just include remote files? (As far as I know)

What are my options? And if there are no options left, should I reconsider using `allow_url_fopen` but implementing security methods to avoid attacks, etc?